# RTC power supply

Tags: stm32, lipo, ldo, rtc

The main task is to power STM32L476 RTC directly from li-po battery (3,7V-4,2V). Unfortunately I don't have enough space for supercap or extra battery. The RTC needs only about 450 nA and has quite wide voltage range from 1,5V to 3,6V. What is the best option to power this thing? The only efficient idea that come to my mind is LDO. Does the LDO has any minimum current?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 3.3 V LDO doesn't sound all that bad.  Basically, the 450 nA will be drained directly from the battery, without any advantage gained by the battery having a higher voltage.  When the battery is at 4.2 V, then the efficiency is 79%.  When the battery is at 3.7 V, the efficiency is 89%.  That doesn't sound too bad for something so very low power in the first place.

Comment: I can't find any info about minimum current. Is there any limitation?

Comment: @KRo: If the LDO datasheet doesn't mention minimum required output current, then you can assume there is no such requirement.  There are certainly many LDOs that don't have a minimum current requirement.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this, please explain what you think is wrong, misleading, or badly written.  I don't see it.

Comment: What about the quiescent current of the LDO? That becomes the biggest factor in the efficiency calculation. The [lowest I can find](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps783.pdf) in a quick search is 500 nA, for which the efficiency would be limited to 42% at best with a 3.7V input.

Comment: @Dave: Yeah, that's a good point.  Normally you can ignore that, but in this case it is significant.  450 nA is *tiny*.  I just checked a ordinary LDO, the MCP1700, and it has a worst case quiescient current of 4 uA, typically 1.6 uA.  At this level you have to consider the self-discharge current of the battery too.  That might be even larger.

Comment: @DaveTweed Well, thats true. I'll use MCP1700-3.3V with 1.8uA quiescent current. I know it's quite a lot in a low power application but is there any other option?

Comment: @KRo: Dave has a good point.  You should chose the LDO carefully by quiescent current.  Look around for ones specifically with low current.  However, what's the self-discharge current of the battery?  The quiescent current won't matter much if it's just a few percent of what the battery is draining from itself anyway.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I'll be using 450mAh LiPo, [datasheet](http://www.tme.eu/en/Document/44c6375e91e60e9847d3235dfd55dd2f/Cellevia%20specification%20502248.pdf) doesn't specify self-discharge rate. If we assume 5%/month it will be about 22,5mAh/month, 0,75mAh/day